# Use local variables and multi query command with mysql and C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to use a two line query to a mysql database like this with C#:
`` set @var = 1; select id from table where id = @var`; ``
Executing this in C# does not give any error, the reader has columns, but don't have rows in it, so, no data is retrieved.

Running the same queries in the workbench retrieve the expected data.
Running one query to calculate the variable and other to use it replaced works.

I want to use a variable to store references and use it to filter queries that provide an union.

`SET @my_value = (select min(id) from (select id from datatable limit 2000) as a);`

and a complex select query, that i can resume in:

`select * from 
   datatable as a 
    left join (
    (select databalt2 where id > @my_value) as ba union 
    (select datatable3 where id > @my_value) as bb) as b 
    on a.id = b.id 
    where a.id > @my_value;`

The datareader should obtain the results, but instead reports that it has no rows, but has the correct amount of columns.
And, obviously, shows no results, where it should.

Edit 1: C# code

```
string query = @"
   SET @`my_value` = (select min(id) from (select id from datatable limit 2000) as a);
   select * from 
   datatable as a 
   left join (
    (select databalt2 where id > @`my_value`) as ba union 
    (select datatable3 where id > @`my_value`)    as bb) as b 
   on a.id = b.id 
   where a.id > @`my_value`;
 ";
 try
 {
  MySqlCommand command = Connection.CreateCommand();
  MySqlDataReader reader;
  command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
  command.CommandText = query;
  reader = command.ExecuteReader();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {

 }
```

Comment: You didn't post any C# code

Comment: Can you show your C# code? Without it I cannot tell if there are some errors.

Comment: Try without the where to see if you get any results.  If you do then the id and my_value may be different types (integers vs. string).

Comment: sorry, i forgot about the c#. The query can be copy/pasted in workbench and works.

Comment: it was missing the `` in the local sql variable.

Answer (score 0):

These queries using local variables are possible, the local variable has to be inside `` like @`var`, because it can be identifyied as a local parameter.
I was missing a `` in a local variable call. So ... a problem between the screen and the chair!